# gnome-session error on rhel (canberra-gtk-module error)

Tags: rhel, gnome, vnc, gtk

When starting cppeclipse in gnome-session via vnc it appears following error on rh6
canberra-gtk-module not found,
module is present in `/usr/lib/x64/` also fails when `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x64/` is exported,
is solution purging/installing of the current libcanberra-gtk3-module ?

Answer (score 0):

Does `cppeclipse` exit with error, or does it start anyway?
canberra-gtk-module is a sound-related module, afaik. So if you're on a VNC session, or perfoming X-forwarding such errors are common, but can be ignored if you don't need any sound. VNC & X-forwarding do not have sound support either.

If `cppeclipse` does not start, or you just don't want the error, you could install on the vnc-machine:

```
yum install libcanberra-gtk2
```

Comment: ok, i can avoid libcanbera since it is sound related, cppeclispe starts ok but i have error extension "RANDR" missing, but i can do in ecclipse, strange thing is that after some time gnome-session overloads machine and crashes, thank you for posting